# Display hyperlink into shiny::info

Tags: shiny

I want to insert a fixed hyperlink in a shiny::info pop up

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- (
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
      id = "main_page",
      fluidRow( # -------------------------------------------------------
                infoBox(title=NULL, icon=shiny::icon(""), subtitle = HTML("<a id=\"infobutton\" 
href=\"#\" class=\"action-button\"><i class=\"fa fa-info-circle\"></i></a>"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- (
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$infobutton, {
      shinyjs::info("It's me Mario")
    })
  }
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've tried with a `TagList` but the pop up just display what's inside the tagList

```
shinyjs::info(tagList("It' me Mario:", a("Mario", href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario")))
```

Thanks !

Comment: from which dependency do you get the `infoBox` function? `shinydashboard`? I'm getting an error when running the function, it's not specified in your code

Comment: Ah sorry, yes shinydashboard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (or should not) be able to insert HTML into there. It only supports plain text.

`shinyjs::info()` is running the javascript `alert()` function - [here's the official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) for it.

Notice the message parameter is:

> A string you want to display in the alert dialog, or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string and displayed.

It's not meant to accept HTML. I'm honestly very surprised that it's able to parse HTML within RStudio, browsers are supposed to only show plain text. If you want to show a pop up message with HTML you need to use something more advanced like `shinyalert` package or shiny modals.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly generate the needed HTML with `HTML`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- (
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
      id = "main_page",
      fluidRow( # -------------------------------------------------------
                infoBox(title=NULL, icon=shiny::icon(""), subtitle = HTML("<a id=\"infobutton\" 
href=\"#\" class=\"action-button\"><i class=\"fa fa-info-circle\"></i></a>"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- (
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$infobutton, {
      shinyjs::info(HTML("<p>It's me Mario:</p> <a  href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario'>Mario</a>"))
    })
  }
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This ouputs me what's inside the HTML : `<p>It's me Mario:</p> <a  href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario'>Mario</a>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I only tested it in RStudio, where it works, but not in the browser, where it doesn't work. Unfortunately, I don't know what exactly goes wrong

Comment: Which browser did you try ? For me it's not working under google chrome

Comment: Not working with Firefox either; only with the built-in browser from RStudio

Comment: Maybe directly make an issue in the `shinyjs` github repository